# How to safely remove gtk2.0 from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gtk-2

I've just installed gtk2 by typing: sudo apt install gtk2.0,
./configure of one package asked for this gtk2
now I don't need it and I want to remove it, when I type: sudo apt remove gtk2.0, I got:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  flowblade gimp gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gpicview gtk2.0-examples ibus-gtk inkscape kasumi kdenlive
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libexo-1-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgarcon-1-0
  libgarcon-gtk3-1-0 libgimp2.0 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil-dev
  libgtk2.0-common libgtk2.0-dev libgtk2.0-doc libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkspell0 libmlt++3 libmlt6
  librccgtk2-0 libunique-1.0-0 libxfce4ui-1-0 lxappearance melt monodoc-gtk2.0-manual pidgin
  pinentry-gtk2 python-gtk2 python3-mlt qt5-gtk2-platformtheme qt5-style-plugins shotcut uim-gtk2.0
  uim-gtk2.0-immodule viewnior xboard xfce4 xfce4-appfinder xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-notes
  xfce4-notes-plugin xfce4-panel xfce4-screensaver xfce4-session xfce4-settings
  xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfdesktop4 xubuntu-core xubuntu-default-settings
  xubuntu-desktop
```

so it will remove all my xubuntu/xfce environment... wtf?
???
why so

**ADDED:**
After reboot, the looks of some of my apps have changed, I think some app uses gtk, and because I've changed the version to gtk2, then appearance has changed. I think even better, I like the looks of sliders for instance. But the color scheme is now very bad.

That was an very old packages, I was anyway unable to install it... I think now I should run `sudo apt-get install gtk3`

Comment: Are you sure that the package you installed to satisfy the ./configure requirement was really `gtk2.0`? it's more likely to have been the development package `libgtk2.0-dev`

Comment: Please be careful with package names. Do not invent not-existing names. You should consult with https://packages.ubuntu.com for actual package names for your release.

Comment: You should look at `/var/log/apt/*` to see which packages you installed, which packages were installed for you, and when.

Comment: After reboot, the looks of some of my apps have changed, I think some app uses gtk, and because I've changed the version to gtk2, then appearance has changed. I think even better, I like the looks of sliders for instance. But the color scheme is now very bad.